# border-opacity transition failure when loading/reloading page in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, border, opacity, css-transitions

I searched the web and stackoverflow for this problem, but I didn't seem to find a solution for my problem. I try to make it so when you hover on a list item, there will appear a bottom-border from 0 to 100% opacity. But when I load/reload the page there appears a border under my list item and is removed instantly. Here are a few images to illustrate what I mean:

1) loading/reloading the page (border shown)
[image: Border is shown on reload]

2) The border dissapears (it should actually start like this!)
[image: like it should be when first loaded]

3) When hovered (after the transition is complete)
[image: when hovered]

4) Here is a [link to the website](http://student.devine.be/nicholas.olivier/nchls) I'm currently working on. Chrome version: 22.0.1229.94

Here the html and css I use:

**A) HTML**

```
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="index.html#">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#">contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#">find me</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#">downloads</a></li>
        </ul>
```

**B) CSS**

```
#menu li+li:before
{
    content: '//';
    color:#e27c18;
    font-size:1.2em;
    margin-right:10px;
}

#menu li a
{
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(226, 124, 24, 0);
    -webkit-transition:border-bottom-color 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    -moz-transition:border-bottom-color 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    -o-transition:border-bottom-color 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    transition:border-bottom-color 300ms ease-in 200ms;
}
#menu li a:hover
{
    border-bottom:1px solid #e27c18;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(226, 124, 24, 1);
    -webkit-transition:border-bottom 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    -moz-transition:border-bottom 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    -o-transition:border-bottom 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    transition:border-bottom 300ms ease-in 200ms;
}
```

Now the thing I want is that when you reload or load the page, that there is not a visible border with correct transitions (this is the only way the transitions react correctly).

**EDIT: I noticed that only a few people have this problem, wich makes it a lot harder to fix this bug :/.**

Comment: I've tested your code and doesn't produce the bug you mention for me. Here's a jsFiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/zQzdQ/ Maybe it's something else in your page that's causing the initial underline?

Comment: @alexg Hmmm that is very strange, would you like me to post the full code of what I have atm on my webspace so you can test it out?

Comment: http://student.devine.be/nicholas.olivier/nchls/ here it is clear what it does, btw my chrome version is: 22.0.1229.94

Comment: We have the same version and I couldn't reproduce the bug at the link you gave either. I tried two computers with different OSes/hardware. Try and see if the problem persists if you remove the font. It could be that the problem depends on one particular format being used, e.g. ttf or svg.

Comment: Nah it is a problem with the bottom border,I'm sure of it. Also a few friends encountered this problem on their mac